# How ignore inside map element?

Tags: reactjs

I have been struggling with a problem.
I have multidimensional array and i want to display it to table body.
so i tried to do it with map, however i can't ignore the top of map element, so it displays like nest data.

this is how the multidimensioanl array looks

```html
 ['2022-05-04', '2022-05-04', '2022-05-04', '2022-05-04', '2022-05-04', '2022-05-04']
 ['10:11:52', '10:11:52', '10:11:53', '10:11:54', '10:11:55', '10:11:56']
 ['447', '442', '447', '442', '436', '433']
```

so i tried to let it looks easy like below.

```html
<tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>{list[0][0]}</td>
            <td>{list[1][0]}</td>
            <td>{list[2][0]}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>{list[0][1]}</td>
            <td>{list[1][1]}</td>
            <td>{list[2][1]}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>{list[0][2]}</td>
            <td>{list[1][2]}</td>
            <td>{list[2][2]}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>{list[0][3]}</td>
            <td>{list[1][3]}</td>
            <td>{list[2][3]}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>{list[0][4]}</td>
            <td>{list[1][4]}</td>
            <td>{list[2][4]}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

so i tried to use map instead of doing this

```html
const tableData = list.map((data, index) =>
    data.map((item, idx) => (
      <tr>
        <td>{listData[idx]}</td>
      </tr>
    ))
  );
  
  return( 
       <tbody>
          {tableData}
          </tbody>
          )
```

it doesn't look what i expected.
how can i solve this problem ??
"tr" tag length should be longest
but "td" tag length should be the multidimensioanl array length.

Comment: yeah this is reactjsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data, as-is, isn't really suited to `.map` because you need to iterate over the `list[x][y]`s, where the `x` changes, but not the `y`. Turn the list into a structure where mapping will work first by essentially turning the multidimensional array on its side.

```
const tableData = list[0].map(
    (_, i) => (
        <tr>
            {
                list.map(
                    listItem => <td>{listItem[i]}</td>
                )
            }
        </tr>
    )
);
return (
    <tbody>
        {tableData}
    </tbody>
)
```